# arcgis desktop selection layer

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms

I have Desktop 10.1 that is accessing data from sde geodatabase.
I select some features on the map, and try to do "Create layer from selected feature"
but nothing happen, and no error message.
the operation was successful when I had sde geodatabase 9.3, but since I migrated sde geodatabase to 10.1 and I cannot do that.

The RDBMS is oracle.

I check for errors in 
c:\users{my user}\AppData\local\Esri\
and nothing related to any error

or this location
c:\users{my user}\AppData\roaming\Esri\

Where are the selection layers saved?
are they saved in the map document?

Comment: Are you creating a new layer from the layer which you have features selected on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for the answers 
I think I found the problem.
It is related to the configuration of SDE_logfiles.
We had old geodatabase/SDE (9.3) and users schemas defined to use the shared sde_logfiles.

But the DBA who created our new geodatabase kept the "per session " setting.
So, the login user was expecting the sde_logfiles to be there.

I am not sure yet, if this is the solution, the DBA is coming next week, and don't have access to the SDE schema.

But I traced back the sql statements the user logged in are submitting in Oracle, and I found that they are trying to access SDE_Logfiles in the same schema as the user.
and in the old sde 9.3 we had all sde_logfiles in the SDE schemas

Answer (score 1):

You should see the new layer added to the Table of Contents (from where it can be saved to the map), but this sounds a lot like the bug below, which was meant to have been resolved at ArcGIS 9.x.

**[Bug:  'Create layer from selected features' does not add new layer to display tab in ArcMap when in layout](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/32712)**

If it sounds exactly like what you are seeing at **ArcGIS for Desktop 10.1** with **ArcSDE 9.3** then I recommend that you report it to your local Esri support.

If you are seeing this when you are in Layout View then a workaround may be to do it in Data View instead.